# Unable to access environment variables in google cloud (node js express app)

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, environment-variables

I am a beginner trying to learn web development. I have built small node js app and deployed in heroku. I am trying to do the same in GCP and learn the platform.

Code used is @ https://github.com/unnikrishnan-r/firstgcpdeployment

The issue that I am facing is **Unable to access env variables in the app**

My **index.js**

```
exports.envVar = (req, res) => {
    // Sends 'bar' as response
    console.log("bbbccc");
    console.log(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
    res.status(200).send(process.env.JAWSDB_URL);
    return process.env.JAWSDB_URL;
  };
```

**.env.yaml** is
`JAWSDB_URL: testtest456`

I then used below to deploy the function to gcloud
`gcloud functions deploy envVar --env-vars-file .env.yaml --runtime nodejs8 --trigger-http;`

Deployment was successful and was tested using console and 
https://us-central1-howtodeployingcp.cloudfunctions.net/envVar

**During deploy this happened**
[image: img]

Can some one help me here?

Comment: I pulled your project, performed the exact same gcloud command and then executed curl against the function and everything worked exactly as desired.  I could not recreate your issue at all.

Comment: @kolban were you able to access `process.env.JAWSDB_URL` and get its value?

Comment: when I ran curl https://****.cloudfunctions.net/envVar I got back testtest456.  I made no changes to your environment.

Answer (score 1):

It seems [this line](https://github.com/unnikrishnan-r/firstgcpdeployment/blob/master/server.js#L14) is problematic:

```
var dbUrl = envVar.envVar();
```

You're calling the function without passing in `req, res` as it's expecting. Perhaps you forgot to comment out [this line](https://github.com/unnikrishnan-r/firstgcpdeployment/blob/master/index.js#L5).

Comment: But even then 
```console.log(`ENV VAR: ${process.env.JAWSDB_URL}`)``` prints `undefined`.

Basically my problem is that I am unable to use the env variable passed in `.env.yaml`

Comment: @unni_ramachandran this is exactly what i am facing right now, did you find a fix for this ?